# How do I output Unicode characters as a pair of ASCII characters?

Tags: c#, unicode, m3u

How do I convert (as an example):

> Señor Coconut Y Su Conjunto - Introducciõn

to:

> SeÃ±or Coconut Y Su Conjunto - IntroducciÃµn

I've got an app that creates m3u playlists, but when the track filename, artist or title contains non ASCII characters it doesn't get read properly by the music player so the track doesn't get played.

I've discovered that if I write the track out as:

```
#EXTINFUTF8:76,SeÃ±or Coconut Y Su Conjunto - IntroducciÃµn
#EXTINF:76,Señor Coconut Y Su Conjunto - Introducciõn
#UTF8:01-IntroducciÃµn.mp3
01-Introducciõn.mp3
```

Then the music player will read it correctly and play the track.

My problem is that I can't find the information I need to be able to do the conversion properly.

I've tried the following:

```
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output);
    foreach (Byte b in byteArray)
    {
        playList.Write(b);
    }
```

where `playList = new StreamWriter(filename, false);` but I just get a series of numbers output:

```
#EXTINFUTF8:76,83101195177111114326711199111110117116328932831173267111110106117110116111 - 731101161141111001179999105195181110
```

which I guess are the numerical values of the characters rather than the characters themselves.

It's been a while since I've done this low level character manipulation and I'm a little rusty.

**UPDATE**

I've now got:

```
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output);
    foreach (Byte b in byteArray)
    {
        playList.Write(Convert.ToChar(b));
    }
```

to do the output and at first glance it appeared to be working. The file as seen in Notepad++ is showing the correct information. However, the first track still isn't being played.

Comment: playList.Write("{0}", b);

this converts byte to number.

Comment: @Andrey - I realise that ;) I don't know what to replace it with.

Comment: see my comments for my answer

Comment: Off-topic comment: The word in the filename ought to be "introducción", not "introducciõn". :-)

Comment: @asveikau - off topic answer: you may well be right. On topic answer: I've looked, but have clearly used the wrong search terms as I've not found what I need. Hence my question here.

Comment: How are you opening playList? If you open it as a `TextWriter` with the UTF-8 encoding, you should just be able to write your strings and have them converted for you. Otherwise, what's happening is you're writing `Write(b)` which is the same as `Write((int)b)` which is the integer values.

Comment: @lavinio - I'm opening playList like this: `var playList = new StreamWriter(filename, false);`

Comment: Have you tried casting the byte to a char?  playlist.Write((char)b); (or look for a WriteByte method).  I'm not sure if you can get a new char(b) if the cast doesn't work.  If Write doesn't take a char you may have to form a one-char string:  new string(c, 1); (or maybe works without ,1 as well).

Comment: @Rob - I was just about to post an update. I've just tried `playList.Write(Convert.ToChar(b));` and it worked (well almost - the first track isn't getting played)

Comment: what exactly is 'playlist'? If it's a Stream it ought to work. If it's a TextWriter then it won't. You have to solve writing the #EXTINF leader and the Byte array to the same destination.

Comment: @Henk - `playList` is a `StreamWriter` - I should have mentioned that in the question

Comment: In case you missed this in the comments on Andrey's answer... If it doesn't like extended-ASCII (high-bit), you might try Encoding.UTF7 instead.  Presumably that would keep it to 7-bit values with the high-bit clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the whole stream to be in UTF-8.  Try:

```
StreamWriter playList = new StreamWriter(filename, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Now, to write to the stream, just pass your `String` named `output` like this:

```
playList.Write(output);
```

The stream will now all be in the proper encoding, so you should also just be able to do something like:

```
playList.WriteLine("#EXTINFUTF8:76,Señor Coconut Y Su Conjunto - Introducciõn");
```

Comment: Yes - that did it. I realised this myself last night as I was dropping off to sleep & was just about to try it when I saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

well, try to write the encoding player expects. and it is utf8! (i guess)

```
byte[] bytesToWrite = Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes(yourString);
```

see that: `#UTF8` in your sample?

Comment: I should have added that I've tried that, but just get a series of numbers.

Comment: then you output bytes to file incorrectly. i bet (10 bucks :) ) that it IS utf8. just output it correctly

Comment: use StreamWriter and pass Encoding.Utf8 to ctor. it will do the trick

Comment: create StreamWriter with this ctor http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f5f5x7kt.aspx then call WriteLine(output) or Write(output). in this case you don't need to call GetBytes

Comment: That just outputs exactly the same character string "Señor" not "SeÃ±or" (for example).

Comment: how do you check that? using notepad? open file with hex editor or smart notepad++. Señor is same as SeÃ±or depending on encoding you open it with.

Comment: or when using notepad click Open and pick ASCII there

Comment: I've got an m3u file generated by MediaMonkey and I'm checking it in Notepad++. It displays the same in Notepad too. I know "Señor" not "SeÃ±or" are the same, but I need to have the file with no high ASCII characters (as we used to call them) for MM to understand it.

Comment: Try Encoding.UTF7.  That should keep the high bit out of it.

Comment: click in notepad++, click Encoding, Character Set, Western European, ISO 8859-1 then copy-paste SeÃ±or there. then click Encoding, Encode in UTF-8 and witness how SeÃ±or turns into Señor. you need just to output your file in C# in UTF8. I gave you the link to msdn.